# What C-data type do I have to use?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to call an external function in the head of which there is something like

```
void asd(unsigned int *&name)
```

My question is now what type of variable is name? I know it should function as an array but I am a bit confused, as passing a simple unsigned-int-array did not work.

edit:

Due to the kind help of you I tried:

```
unsigned int* name[];
asd(feld);
```

which gives me an error like "storage size of name isn't known" but when I write

```
unsigned int* name[10];
asd(feld);
```

I get "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type unsigned int& from a temporary of type int". Now I get really confused.

Comment: It is a reference to a pointer to `unsigned int`, so it will accept and `unsigned int*` lvalues.

Comment: I have nothing to add to juanchopanza's answer, so I'm not answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is a reference to a pointer to `unsigned int`, so it will accept `unsigned int*` lvalues. For example,

```
unsigned int* p = nullptr;
asd(p);
```

The fact that is is being passed by reference means that the function `asd` can change the value of the pointer passed to it, and this change is seen by the caller.

Comment: @stefan Thanks. I meant "any", but even that was redundant.